# __module__ usage with the os module

Tags: python

```
import os
print(os.listdir.__module__)
```

That code outputs `posix`, but [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-33) say:

> The name of the module the function was defined in, or `None` if unavailable.

Comment: Perhaps os.listdir is a wrapper

Comment: `os` is a shim package, it delegates to the corresponding OS-specific package. `posix` is the `os` package for POSIX and POSIX-like systems.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.name; that is indeed the name of the module that function was defined in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your machine (Unix), `os.listdir` was defined in the [`posix` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/posix.html). It's that simple.

```
>>> os.listdir is posix.listdir
True
```

Comment: thanks i know it's not a big deal but i just wanted to know why